# Get Current location of Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an Ifram and I want to get its current location url when a user click the content.

```
 <iframe src="http://www.Mysite.com/login.aspx" width="100%" height="800"  id="iframeid" ></iframe>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#iframeid").load(function () {
            try{
                alert(this.contentWindow.location.href);// do what you want with this location
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                alert(err.message);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I use this code but does not return any value.

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").get(0).contentWindow.location.url
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.url
document.getElementById("iframe_id").documentWindow.location.href
```

I get the error: "Permission denied to access property 'href'"

How to get Current location url?

Comment: I searched in google, and I've tried all methods that find, but don't any methods work for me.

Comment: Are you trying to access an iframe from a different domain?  Can you post your code?

Comment: Yes, I use it in differnet domain. Plz see my edit